# nodejs, error http Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

estoy haciendo una peticion al backend donde me tiene que devolver publicaciones,e ste es mi endpoint:

```
private async _Publicaciones(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response>{
const { _id }: any = req.user
try{
  const resp: any = await Usuario.findById(_id)
  .populate({path: 'seguidos'})
  .sort({createdAt: 1})
  const ids = [ _id ]
  for(let key of resp.seguidos){
    ids.push(key)
  }
  const response = await Publicacion.find({ de: {$in: ids} })
                          .populate({path: 'de'})
  return res.status(200).json(response)
 }catch(error){
  console.log(error)
  return res.status(400).json(error)
 }
}
```

no estaria entendiendo por que estoy teniendo este error

Comment: ¿Cómo y dónde estás usando esa función llamada `_Publicaciones`?

Comment: en si, no es una función es un método privado y asíncrono dentro de una clase, dicha clase tambien contiene un metodo llamado `_routes`, donde esta estableciendo una consulta get de esta manera `this._router.get('/publicaciones', this._Publicaciones)`

Comment: En el código no se ve el problema. Al parecer hay algún tipo de error que puede ser externo a la instancia de dicha clase, revisa bien la forma en que creas la instancia y si por casualidad estás creando más de una instancia. Tal vez necesites usar algún patrón como Singleton para segurarte que sólo puedes crear una instancia de dicha clase, o tal vez algún otro patrón como DIC (Dependency Injector Container) si no deseas usar Singleton. Saludos

Comment: la verdad es que estoy totalmente perdido en este momento, estoy con este proyecto desde principio de año, incluso tengo varias rutas definidas del mismo modo, en las clases de las rutas tengo varios métodos y nunca me había encontrado con este problema, todos mis endpoints estas definidos de la misma manera y sin ningún problema

Comment: quiero agregar que este problema no esta siendo constante, al hacer las peticiones, algunas veces las hace bien, otras veces me tira este error, no es constante, es por momento, pero obviamente debo solucionarlo

Comment: No estoy seguro de si implementar clases para el manejo de rutas sea lo adecuado. Es que no me cuadra para nada mezclar la lógica del controlador con entidades de OOP.

Comment: en todos los mis proyectos como programador realice el backend con clases, no digo que no utilizo programación funcional, sino que la manera de hacer esto con clases es muchísimo mas legible para mi, y muchísimo mas escalable a mi parecer

Comment: Este error lo que te dice es que estás intentando mandar una respuesta cuando ya has mandado una. Dicho de forma más sencilla, estas haciendo un `res.json()` o un `res.send()` cuando ya has hecho uno. Así que yo te diría que revises todos y cada uno de los middlewares y metodos en los que haces una devolución y analices si entra en más de uno a la vez.